# 1064 syntax error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am confused. I don't know what is the error.  On execution I got a message:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'group(creator,type,name,details,icon)values (6,'information
>   sharing','test','j' at line 1"

my query is :

```
INSERT INTO group 
    (creator, type, name, details, icon) VALUES
    (6, 'information sharing', 'test', 'just for testing',
    'My friend/group_uploads/pic00_6_0d46839f6371fb84f6b6c682f5fc2c77.jpeg')
```

this my table specification:

```
type      varchar(1000)
name      varchar(1000)
details   varchar(1000)
creator   bigint(20)
icon      varchar(1000)
```

please help me to correct the error .

Comment: just change table name "grou" to "grp" and try this query in PHP "INSERT INTO grp (type, name, details, creator, icon) VALUES
('6', 'information sharing', 'test', '0', 'My friend/group_uploads/pic00_6_0d46839f6371fb84f6b6c682f5fc2c77.jpeg');" @Shankar Damodaran is right group makes problem because of reserved word

Answer (score 3):

`group` is a [`reserved word`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to surround it in backticks.

Like this..

```
insert into `group`(creator, type, name, details, icon) values ('6','information sharing','test','just for testing','My friend/group_uploads/pic00_6_0d46839f6371fb84f6b6c682f5fc2c77.jpeg')
            ^     ^
```

Try to avoid having such names for your columns and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Grou is Keywords in MySQL. So use backticks for those.

Try:

```
 INSERT INTO `group` 
        (`creator`, `type`, `name`, `details`, `icon`) VALUES
        (6, 'information sharing', 'test', 'just for testing',
        'My friend/group_uploads/pic00_6_0d46839f6371fb84f6b6c682f5fc2c77.jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though by using  backticks you can use keywords as table name , **It is not recommended to use reserved word as table name**

DO NOT DO IT.

Official list of reserved keywords: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)